# retrieving value from sprintf function?

Tags: matlab

i'm looking for advice to see if anyone knows how to get this working...
i have an number of player names which i'd like to convert in to numbers to store in a list.

```
for k = 1:player_name;
    pn = sprintf('Enter the name of player %d', k);
    inputdlg(pn);
end
```

for example, i'd like to retrieve the name of player 2.
i was thinking something like:

```
player1 = str2num(pn %d, k);
```

but i can't get this working...
any ideas greatly recieved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
numPlayers = inputdlg('Enter the number of players');
numPlayers = str2num(numPlayers{1});

for i=1:numPlayers
    name{i} = inputdlg(['Enter the name of player ' num2str(i)]);
end
```

now to access player 1's name

```
name1 = name{1}
```

Comment: hey twerdster or anyone reading, is it possible to convert the player name into a number? i tried simply changing:     name{i} = inputdlg(['Enter the name of player ' str2num(i)]);    but it doesn't work that way....any ideas? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by number? If I enter the name "Peter" what kind of number do you want from that? A hash function?

Comment: i mean the position i think, instead of a name if i asked for a position on the field, something like: ask for the number of players,ask for the player name, ask for the player number and position. then i'd like to be able to use the position attribute as an integer...i hope this makes sense, i'm not sure i'd fully thought my question out initially!thanks for your help!

Comment: @richy1000 I think your question is too specific now. Im not sure what field youre talking about or what position youre referring to.